# AS3 LocalConnection: function is not firing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm building an AIR app that sends text string to a swf-file. When I export the sender and reciever apps to swf and run them in Flash players, everything works well. But when publishing the sender app to AIR things don't work anymore.

I think the connection works, because there are no error messages. But the function on reciever swf won't fire.

Here's my code for **AIR** (the sender):

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var conn:LocalConnection;
conn = new LocalConnection();
conn.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onLocalConnError);

function send_it(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    conn.send('_connection', 'fire','myString');
}

function onLocalConnError(e:StatusEvent):void
{
    teksti.text = e.toString();
}


btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send_it);
```

And the reciever **SWF:**

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var conn:LocalConnection;

function connect(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    conn = new LocalConnection();
    conn.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onLocalConnError);
    conn.allowDomain("app#fi.myapp");
    conn.client = this;
    conn.connect('_connection');
    this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeConnection);
}

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, connect);


function onLocalConnError(e:StatusEvent):void
{
    my_text.text = e.toString();
}

function fire(txt:String):void
{
    my_text.text = txt;
}

function closeConnection(e:Event = null):void
{
    conn.close();
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identifier the receiving app PLUS the connectionname in the `send`-call:

```
conn.send('app#YourReceivingAppName:_connection', 'fire','myString');
```

Greetings

Comment: The recieving app is just a swf-file. So should this work: conn.send('app#recieve.swf:_connection', 'fire', 'myString');

Comment: Ah ok. In this case your code is absolutely right! You have to set the publishing settings of the swf to "network only". This should work.